# B grade 80's movie about a commando hunted like an animal

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw this movie as a kid in the 80s.

A terror / paramilitary group runs a training camp, where they kidnap men and leave them in the forest, and then get the trainees to hunt and kill them.

By mistake, they kidnap a commando, and he starts killing them off instead. The bad guys are the ones running for their life now. Other salient details:

- It was a real B grade movie, but with a good music score. The hero was really buff, though I didn't see him in any other movie.
- Once the hero starts killing them off, they kidnap his wife and kill her. The hero catches the guy who killed his wife, cuts off his arm, and beats him to death with it. He then scalps him.
- In the end, he captures the head of the training camp, strips him, and forces him to run in the forest. The movie ends with the hero then hunting him.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your thinking of Deadly Prey from 1986. The plot, as taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadly_Prey) is

> Colonel Hogan rents his mercenaries out to anyone with the right
>   price. This time it's businessman Michaelson. A deal is struck, and
>   Hogan recruits new troops. For training, he orders his troops to
>   kidnap innocent people, take them to the forest and hunt them.
>   Unfortunately this time, they picked the wrong guy, Mike Danton.
>   Danton, a Vietnam veteran, is ambushed while taking out the trash.
>   Taken to the forest, he is stripped to his shorts, greased up and told
>   to run. The mercenaries hunt Danton, but are meticulously picked off
>   one by one. The troops report this to Colonel Hogan, who sends a task
>   force with his best man, Lieutenant Thornton. One of this elite combat
>   unit is Jack Cooper. Cooper and Danton realize who each other are
>   while trying to kill each other. Cooper has not seen Danton since he
>   took a bullet for him in 'Nam. With his new-found friend, Danton
>   continues to punish the mercenaries, and get back to his wife Jaimey.
>   Like all good villains, Hogan uses Danton's family against him, but
>   this angers Danton. After storming the military training camp Danton
>   arms himself up, and destroys all traces of Hogan's mercenaries.

There is an extended trailer on YouTube [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQySDbFb97s). At the 5:50 mark you can see the scene where Denton cuts of the guys arm and beats him with it.

Comment: Bravo for finding the answer so quickly!