80s movie where guy is hunted in woods and fights back
I saw this movie in early 90s as young kid and want to see it again. But I need you to identify it. What I remember:

I believe the movie was 80s or very early 90s release
Guy with military background is kidnapped for some ill game where he is hunted in woods
He survives initial hunt and fights back
During the film, main hero dislocates his shoulder and puts it back, self help (I remember scene about this)
Main hero has bright color of hair, possibly blonde
Also I am pretty sure that if main hero would be well known actor (like Jean-Claude Van Damme), I would remember it


I want to say Hard Target (1993) starring Jean Claude Van Damme. There's also Surviving the Game (1994) starring Ice T, but he doesn't seem to fit your description.

@Dannie I added to question itself, that I am pretty sure that I would remember actors like Jean Claude Van Damme. The "Surviving the game" looks almost like the movie. But I am really really sure the main actor was white dude with blonde-ish hair

http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11980/b-grade-80s-movie-about-a-commando-hunted-like-an-animal - Is this what you're looking for?

@Dannie YES! Thats exactly it! Thank you so much. Will mark it as duplicate
